# Populating a 2d array with another 2 array

Tags: java, for-loop, complexity-theory, multidimensional-array

```
    void some_function() {
     int d[] = new int[10];
     int e[] = new int[15]; 
     int f[] = new int[20];
     int g[] = new int[25]; 
     int h[] = new int[30];
     int i[] = new int[35];
     int j[] = new int[40];
     int k[] = new int[45];
     int l[] = new int[50];
     int m[] = new int[55];
     int n[] = new int[60];
     int o[] = new int[65];
     int p[] = new int[70];
     int q[] = new int[75];
     int r[] = new int[80];
     int s[] = new int[85];
     int t[] = new int[90];
     int u[] = new int[95];
     int v[] = new int[100];
    //Randomly generate int elements of the array
     int master_list[][] = {d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, 
        o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v};
     Random gen = new Random();
     int i_array[];
     double run_times[][] = new double[19][6];
     double start, end, total_time_1, total_time_2, total_time_3;
     double comp_1, comp_2, comp_3;
     for(int idex = 0; idex < master_list.length; idex++) {
        i_array = master_list[idex];
        //Randomly generate integers to put in each array        
        for(int jdex = 0; jdex < master_list[idex].length; jdex++) {
           i_array[jdex] = gen.nextInt(10);
        }

        comp_1 = ((14*(Math.pow(i_array.length, 2))) 
           + (i_array.length/2) + 4);
        comp_2 = ((14*i_array.length) + 35);
        comp_3 = ((19*i_array.length) + 4);
        /* This is the part where we begin to print and calculate
           data for our report. It begins with caluculating the
            run time of each algorithm by calling the system clock
            method of System.nanoTime() */
        System.out.println("Input size: " + i_array.length);
        System.out.println("Run time of Algorithm 1:");        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        driver.algorithm_1(i_array); 
        end = System.nanoTime();
        total_time_1 = end - start;
        System.out.println("Total time elapsed: " + total_time_1
           + " milliseconds.");
        //We then add this time into the [19][6] matrix.
        run_times[idex][0] = total_time_1;
        run_times[idex][3] = comp_1;

        //The process then repeats for algorithm 2
        System.out.println("Run time of Algorithm 2:"); 
        start = System.nanoTime();
        driver.algorithm_2(i_array); 
        end = System.nanoTime();
        total_time_2 = end - start;
        System.out.println("Total time elapsed: " + total_time_2
           + " milliseconds.");
        run_times[idex][1] = total_time_2; 
        run_times[idex][4] = comp_2; 

        //Yet again another repitition for algorithm 3
        System.out.println("Run time of Algorithm 3:");
        start = System.nanoTime();
        driver.algorithm_3(i_array); 
        end = System.nanoTime();
        total_time_3 = end - start;
        System.out.println("Total time elapsed: " + total_time_3
           + " milliseconds.\n");
        run_times[idex][2] = total_time_3;
        run_times[idex][5] = comp_3;
     }
  }
```

So the issue with this whole thing is that I'm trying to create an array of size run_times[19][6], However, I'm only getting a list of size [10][5].

So, the algorithm is taking int arrays d - v and generating random elements for them. I'm then calculating the run times and complexities of each algorithm (not included).

The run time array is something like this:
     [0][0] = algorithm_1 time
     [0][1] = algorithm_2 time
     [0][2] = algorithm_3 time
     [0][3] = algorithm_1 complexity 
     [0][4] = algorithm_2 complexity
     [0][5] = algorithm_3 complexity

The complexity double is plugging the array size in for n in the T(n) recurrence relation.

Any idea of what's wrong? It compiles and has no run-time errors.

Comment: You should use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `int[]`.

Comment: Wish I could, but the project requires that I use a 2d array :(

Comment: Debug with Eclipse or Idea or any other IDE.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yes, I have compiles and runs without errors. (Just made an edit to clarify that).

Comment: Like @BheshGurung use an `ArrayList<Integer>` and then call `Collection`'s `arrayList.toArray(new Integer[0])`

Comment: What makes you think it's size `[10][5]`? Also, it looks like you're a C programmer - try using standard way of declaring arrays `int[] arr` rather than `int arr[]`. I know the syntax is supported, but no one uses it.